# Override toString method in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, tostring, object-to-string

```
public class Curiosity {



public void toString()//error because of this specific method name 
{
    System.out.println("method is successfully implemented");
}



}
```

***How can i use a method of the same name "toString()" if i want to ?***

Do I have to give its return type as String if not ***what should i do to change its return type like suppose if i want to use a void return type for toString does java allow that ?***

Comment: toString() can't be void, it has to return a String always

Comment: you cannot do that instead just return `null` nothing else but please take care of `nullpointerException`

Answer (score 4):

`toString()` method must return a `String`. That's the only way to override `Object`'s `toString()`.

```
public String toString()
{
    return "method is successfully implemented";
}
```

If you wish to use the same name but **not override** `Object`'s `toString`, you can overload the name `toString` by adding arguments, thus changing the signature of your method.

Example :

```
public void toString (String something)
{
    System.out.println("method is successfully implemented " + something);
}
```

Comment: or just use `return null`  atlernative of void :)

Comment: @BhargavModi yes, but then he wouldn't be able to use toString() properly as any line of code System.out.println(object) would print method is successfully implemented then null, it would look wrong

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to overload toString() method in a wrong manner

Overloaded methods are differentiated by the number and the type of the arguments passed into the method. In the code sample, draw(String s) and draw(int i) are distinct and unique methods because they require different argument types.

You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell them apart.

**The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.**

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use `toString()` in your class is by keeping the return type as `String`

```
public String toString()
{
   //your code here
}
```

That is how it is defined in `Object`class and if you wish to override it you will have to use the exact signature

or if you still wish to use the method name as toString what you can do is change the method's signature.

A method's signature includes method's name and the parameters.
Remember that return type is not a part of a method's signature

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: This is from the oracle docs:
Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source code of the **java.lang.Object**.

The **toString** method have a return value in String type. You can't have another method which's name is **toString** but return type is not String.

Actually, it's forbidden in Java in any inheritance relationship. When you call the method, the compiler only cares the name and the parameters. So how can it distinguishes the methods of the same name but with the different return type?